# Does a word problem provide all information?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, derivatives

A while ago I asked a similar question about word problems and assumptions.

**Is it a definition or an accepted-fact** that word problems provide all information about the relevant existence/situation in the word problem?

Thanks to all!

EDIT, should've been clear. For example a problem like,

"A spherical balloon is inflated with gas at the
rate of 800 cubic centimeters per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon increasing at the instant the radius is (a) 30 centimeters and (b) 60 centimeters?"

Comment: A word problem ordinarily involves using a mathematical model of the situation described by the words. The intended model is often reasonably clear, but in probability word problems, there are often unstated assumptions.

Comment: Also, in order to mimic the real world, word problems may contain irrelevant information as well. I think this should be more common than it is.

Comment: Can anyone give me a reference for word problems - pre-university education in the UK has been wrecked over last 50 years by dumbing down. :(

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen,

So it is **an accepted fact that word problems provide all information about the items that EXIST in the situation?**

Comment: Please don't shout. No, it is not a fact, let alone an accepted one. But if the problem does not contain enough information to solve it, then it is arguably a *bad* problem. But see the caveat by @AndréNicolas above. More generally, there may be unstated assumptions where the author of the problem thinks these assumptions will be universally understood (at least by the intended audience). That s/he may be mistaken about that, is a different matter. (I wonder why you ask?)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You mean word problems now attract more discussion because of improved awareness of minority rights?

Comment: One unstated assumption in the problem you give as an example: No gas is leaking out of the balloon. Another big one has to do with the pressure of the gas in the balloon. Is it constant?

Comment: @almagest That wasn't on my mind, but one can probably come up with examples where implicit assumptions will vary depending on your background culture.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, I suppose we do make assumptions based on how we as humans **communicate**. What I mean is that, from the start this is how we learned to **communicate** That we leave out false information just besides **common sense** What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**$\S1$: A necessary clarification**

It is simply a misunderstanding to think that while some math problems are "word problems", there are others that are not.  For example, any question posted to math.stackexchange.com that omitted words would probably be considered not to be a sufficiently clearly expressed question to remain open.  A list of problems in a textbook might look like this:

> Find the following sums:
>   $1$. ${}\qquad{} 13+28$
>   $2$. ${}\qquad{} 97+42$
>   $3$. ${}\qquad{} 58+19$
>   ${}\  \vdots$
>   ${}\  \vdots$
>   ${}\  \vdots$
>   $48$. ${}\qquad31+67$
>   ${}\  \vdots$
>   ${}\  \vdots$

A student looks at number $48$ and thinks it just says $31+67$, parses the "$+$" as a verb in the imperative mood telling him to find the sum, and concludes that it's not a "word problem" although the words "Find the following sums:" appear at the top.

If it says

> $48$. ${}\qquad x^2-2x+35$

A student asking for help sometimes presents it as if it **only** says $x^2-2x+35$.  If the words at the top say "Factor the following polynomials" then it is quite a different problem from what it would be if it said "Differentiate the following functions of $x$."  But sometimes students posting to math.stackexchange.com write something like this: "How do I do this problem? $x^2-2x+35$?"  That's not really even a question: there is no question in the students mind about how to do something, where the student knows what it is that is to be done.  Obviously all this is a consequence of the fact that a duty is imposed upon students to learn mathematics.  Students who are there because mathematics is something they want to learn ask actual questions.

**$\S2$: The heart of the answer:**

Problems in mathematics books presume students know things before encountering the problem.  If a problem says "How big would the coefficient of friction have to be in order to prevent a car going along a horizontal road with radius of curvature 200 meters from skidding off the road while making the turn?" it would normally be presumed that the concept of coefficient of friction has been defined.

**$\S3$: More examples**

A student who was not a native speaker of English once asked me how I concluded that a certain number should be $12$.  It turned out he did not know the meaning of the word "dozen", which appeared in the statement of the problem.  So just what it is that a student is presumed to know might not be stated explicitly, but that kind of confusion is not what is normally intended.

The physicist Edwin Jaynes once stated a problem approximately as follows: "A very limp piece of string of length $L$ is thrown very unskillfully onto the floor.  Find the probability distribution of the distance between the two ends."  I think he actually intended the reader to know that he expected probability to be construed as logical epistemic probability rather than relative frequency.  But you had to know the context to see that!

Comment: But I never heard about word problems 20 years ago. Why is this site full of the term? When did the fashion come in and why? I am in the UK, not the US, where pre-university maths has been continuously and disastrously dumbed down for the last 50 years. I am extremely wary of this term! :)

Comment: @almagest : I was certaintly hearing that term far more than 20 years ago.  It's been standard among outsiders to mathematics for a long time.  Maybe you never talked to a non-mathematician before you used this site.

Comment: I have worked outside maths for the last 40 years. My contact with mathematicians has been extremely limited. Come to think of it, the only 2 I have talked to on a remotely regular basis are Bela Bollobas and Peter Swinnerton-Dyer and the latter arguably stopped being a mathematician soon after I went to Trinity, Cambridge in 1968!

Comment: @almagest : But were the people you were talking to required to do math problems that they do only because someone told them to?  Among that group the term "word problem" has been standard for more than the amount of time you're speaking of.

Comment: I try only to talk about maths to people who are *unable* to stop thinking about maths.

Comment: @almagest : That explains your unawareness of that standard childish terminology.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHardy, I'm a tad confused.
How does this answer the question =D?

Comment: @Michael Hardy Final off topic comment. I am using this site for a short period because I mainly work in finance and I am trying to figure out the threats and opportunities it poses to current pre-university education. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: Do you mean threats and opportunities posed by finance, or by this site, or by something else? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Aakarsh I am confused now. What do balloons and trivial arithmetic have to do with maths? [As you may possibly not know, "trivial" is a technical term in maths.]

Comment: @Aakarsh  Read the paragraph starting with "Problems in mathematics books presume students know things before encountering the problem." and then giving an example.  That's the heart of the answer.  The part before it is a necessary clarification.  The parts after it are further examples. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Aakarsh : I have now divided my answer into three sections.  Maybe that will make clear the answer to your question here in the comments.

Comment: @MichaelHardy , thank you very much for your reply. So, if you look at my modified question. With the example question, when you say students should know some things before. When you think about the hole, which category of "previous knowledge" does that fall under? Also, are you agreeing with me, that a perhaps "previous knowledge" is knowing the fact that word problems provide enough information prehand??

Comment: In that example, you might be presumed to know from high-school geometry that the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ is $(4/3)\pi r^3$, and you would be expected to know how to do some routine algebra and how to find derivatives.  I wouldn't expect all that to be explained when the problem is stated. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: MichaelHardy, thanks what about the other part? Do word pRrbLes always provide ALL the information?

Comment: What constitutes "all the information" is a judgment call.  Obviously the statement of the problem you give does not tell you how to compute derivatives, nor does it tell you what a sphere is.

Comment: I see where our thoughts are clashing. I meant " do word problems provide all information of what EXISTS there in the situation itself??" Like, you dont assume a hole exists in the balloon from the example. I asked if this is because "a well posed word problem provides all information about what is there in the situation prehand. Correct? In other words, do you agree with this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the hole makes a difference.  Certainly a problem can be badly phrased by omitting information that needs to be there in order that the problem be understood.

Comment: Yes,

It is just a question. So, is it a fact/definition that word problems do provide ALL information. =D

Comment: @Aakarsh : Except that you should remember that there is really no distinction between a "word problem" and any other sort of problem. They're all "word problems".  That another kind exists besied "word problems" is a naive misunderstanding. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yeah, should've been clear. By "word problem," I **specifically** meant problems applying to the world. Modelling, like the edited example (in the question).

So **yes** or **no**, do you **agree** or do you **disagree**?

Comment: A well stated "word problem" gives all information needed to understand the problem, but what is needed depends on context.  A textbook assumes the student has had certain prerequisites, and that's part of the context.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHardy, my point wasn't that.
Here's what I meant: A "word problem" provides **all** relevant information about the **SITUATION** of the story. The situation. not facts such as volume formulas etc.. That is what I meant. **Still agree?** Thanks

Comment: Sometimes "word problems" in textbooks do contain things like "volume formulas" and the like, sometimes as reminders and sometimes expecting that the student will not have known the result before.  But normally they contain all information that distinguishes the particular problem from other problems.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHardy thanks for the reply! One last thing since you did mention past experience is required in word problems!

Could it be that **it is just the way we communicate as humans when we're trying to cooperate**? Maybe that as communication, we **do** ignore unstated things as assuming they don't exist. Exceptions are common sense things. **what do you think**? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly some things are left unstated: my example of the use of the word "dozen" could apply to people who both speak English natively if it had been some bit of mathematical terminology with which one person was familiar, and that person didn't realize the other didn't know that term.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHardy, I meant like the situation of the problem. Like, is it just the way we communicate that we assume what they didn't mention such as the hole, doesn't exist there??? Also, we assume problems take place on earth. What is a reason for that??

Comment: I think it was intended that you would neglect the hole; otherwise it would have been mentioned.